How can I define changed_when based on file content?
I have a few installations on our servers and workstations, which are executed via proprietary setup scripts, for example MATLAB.
Do keep the idempotency I would like to analyze the log file, which is created in the process. How can I define the changed_when based on the content of those log files?
So for example the command task would look like the following at the moment:
- name: Run MATLAB installer
  ansible.builtin.command:
    argv:
      - /mnt/matlabiso/install
      - -inputFile
      - /mnt/downloads/Software/MATLAB/R2024a/installer_input_linux.txt
  changed_when: false

So this command creates a log file at /tmp/ML2024.log, which has the line "Succesful installed" as the last line or "Installation failed" if it was not succesfull. The command itself if remember correctly mostly never fails.
If I understand my linter correctly, changed_when: false and than reading the content of the log file and printing via debug is not a real idempotent way of calling a command, since the changes are already done with the command.
So the actual Question: Did I miss a way how command is able to treat file content, without creating a custom script, which is executing and setup and reading the content afterwards.

Sounds more like a job for Custom facts for me. An other approach could be to search for a string in a Remote File, the log. For a more detailed answer it would be necessary to provide more information on which task, when and where you like to Define changed.

Q: "To keep the idempotency I would like to analyze the log file, which is created in the process."
Still, this looks like a job for Custom facts for me.
Q: "How command is able to treat file content, without creating a custom script, which is executing and setup and reading the content afterwards?"
It isn't and it wasn't made for that. See command module – Execute commands on targets - Notes and at least "Use the ansible.builtin.shell module if you need these features."
Q: "This command creates a log file at /tmp/ML2024.log, which has the line Succesful installed as the last line or Installation failed if it was not succesfull."
That sounds more like Define failure and  the status of failed_when, because it doesn't tells if it was already installed before or not. See a minimal example playbook
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

    - shell:
        cmd: echo 'Installation failed' > /tmp/ML2024.log | grep 'Succesful installed' /tmp/ML2024.log
      register: result

    - debug:
        var: result

resulting into an output of
TASK [shell] *******************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => changed=true
  cmd: echo 'Installation failed' > /tmp/ML2024.log | grep 'Succesful installed' /tmp/ML2024.log
  delta: '0:00:00.007761'
  end: '2024-11-12 09:30:00.347773'
  msg: non-zero return code
  rc: 1
  start: '2024-11-12 09:30:00.340012'
  stderr: ''
  stderr_lines: <omitted>
  stdout: ''
  stdout_lines: <omitted>

Just Registering result and check on Common Return Values will already provide some of the capabilities in question.

I think I was too strict in the past just to use command. I took the "so it is more secure to use the ansible.builtin.command module when possible." too serious. The custom facts approach is meant to create an information based on the result in the log file, so I can create a state of software which is not tracked by the package manager?

"so I can create a state of software which is not tracked by the package manager?", right, that one of the many use cases which it is good for. A more complex example for Custom facts and PostgreSQL Streaming Replication is shown under How to implement and use a Custom Fact?.

You could write your own custom module which would set its value of "changed" based on the logfile. That's a lot of work though.
As you say, the command itself mostly succeeds, and you want a wider idea of "success".
Your best bet seems to be wrapping several commands in a block.
A block lets you run several commands in sequence and treat the set as succeeding or failing, as well as having some cleanup steps you can do in the event of failure.
